# UITabBarView make image a circle

Tags: ios, swift, tabs, uitabbarcontroller, swift2

I am writing application with image, which should be avatar. So I want this avatar to be completely circle. I am using AutoLayout and I know how to make look image perfect circle even with constrains without using delay! But now I am using Tab Bar View (with TabBarView Controller) and when I am trying to open tab with avatar I am facing problem: picture is not complete circle. It is not a rhombus but it is still not a circle. But if I will try other bars and then return to bar with avatar it will be perfect circle. Look in the gif animation below and you will see everything:

[image]

There is the code to do this:

```
@IBOutlet weak var userAvatarImageView: UIImageView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    userAvatarImageView.layer.borderWidth = 4.0
    userAvatarImageView.layer.masksToBounds = true
    userAvatarImageView.clipsToBounds = true
    userAvatarImageView.layer.cornerRadius = userAvatarImageView.bounds.size.width / 2.0
    let color = UIColor(red: CGFloat(255.0), green: CGFloat(255.0), blue: CGFloat(255.0), alpha: CGFloat(1.0))
    userAvatarImageView.layer.borderColor = color.CGColor
}

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    userAvatarImageView.layer.cornerRadius = userAvatarImageView.bounds.size.width / 2.0
}

override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    userAvatarImageView.layer.cornerRadius = userAvatarImageView.bounds.size.width / 2.0
}
```

But none of this methods work properly. Please, maybe someone knows how to fix this?

Comment: I think I have found a solution but it is quite slow: override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
         userAvatarImageView.layer.cornerRadius = userAvatarImageView.bounds.size.width / 2.0
    } Does somebody know a better way?

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem, I found that userAvatarImageView.bounds.size.width / 2.0 this one is not working. So i gave the exact value there and the image then show perfect circle.

```
   userAvatarImageView.layer.cornerRadius = userAvatarImageView.bounds.size.width / 2.0 // Dont use like this 

   userAvatarImageView.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0 ( value which equal to userAvatarImageView.bounds.size.width / 2.0, calculate that value and put it here )
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, sound interesting but I wanted something different. I want method to called just after constrains will load. I think I found one but it is not fast... This method is: override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
         userAvatarImageView.layer.cornerRadius = userAvatarImageView.bounds.size.width / 2.0
    }

Comment: yeah, i also faced this problem, but I didn't find any solution so I used like this :). Hope that this will gonna help you

Comment: Ok, thank you, I will try your method later but for now viewDidAppear maybe enough.